# Деловая переписка

Tags: этикет, деловой-язык

Считается ли моветоном употребление в деловой переписке архаизмов?

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать, какие именно архаизмы Вы имеете в виду. Просто с конкретными примерами вопрос будет яснее.

Comment: Люблю их певучесть и в речи использую, порой не задумываясь: ежели, давеча, ведать, посему, аки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...Широко используются профессионализмы, речевые стандарты, номенклатурные обозначения, типично употребление сложных слов и аббревиатур. Лексика официально-делового стиля может иметь интернациональный характер, **допустимо использование архаизмов**...

**Лексика и фразеология официально-делового стиля**

http://prometod.ru/index.php?type_page&katalog&id=984&met8